# How to use custom id as session id in Flask Socket IO

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using flask socket-io for a basic chat app. But I have a problem. When my device connect to server, flask give to device a session id. But after  disconnect and again connect, session id changes. So, this device can't receive old room's messages. I thought if I'd do if I assign custom session id to device.Is it true? Or what is your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session ids are supposed to be unique, even when a client reconnects. There is no way for an application to choose these ids, they are random numbers chosen by the server.

What you need to do is map a session id to your user information in the connect event, and remove the mapping in the disconnect event. That way at any time you can find out what session id a user is currently on. If you need specific room assignments, those need to be done upon connection, and undone on disconnection.

Comment: Thanks your advice.I solved problem this way.I worried about negative performance.But I could'nt found another way.