# Get the the Flask-Security user id in a Flask-SocketIO event

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-login, flask-socketio

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402185/how-to-use-custom-id-as-session-id-in-flask-socket-io) they say that in order to broadcast a socket.io event to only specific clients, you need to link your user IDs and socket session IDs together somewhere. So in my socket connect event, I want to link those two IDs, but the user session seems to be unavailable in a socket.io event. Is there a way to access the user ID from Flask-Security/Login here?

```py
from flask_security import current_user
from app import socketio

socket_connections = {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("Client connected: " + request.sid)

    # Prints None, even if authenticated
    print(current_user.get_id())

    # Link user ID with session ID
    socket_connections[current_user.get_id() = request.sid]
```

Answer (score 0):

The user session at the time the Socket.IO connection is made is actually accessible in your Socket.IO event handlers, and `current_user` is accessible as well.

You are not showing your code so I cannot tell you what's wrong, but I suggest you try out the Socket.IO example called `sessions.py` which is specifically designed to help you understand how the user session works under Socket.IO. I have even recorded a video with some details about this and a demo of this example application:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ1yQTbtf5E